# Is this sentence "It does don't have a " correct?

Tags: grammar

Someone reported lack of one column on a table. And I Checked table.
I want to emphasize "the problem is true", so I use "It (the table) does don't have a column of XXX". Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say the table is missing a column.  Or the table is missing the XX column.

To provide the most help: The column should have 10 columns. It is missing the fourth column.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly wrong. More accurately:

It doesn't have the column of XXX.

It does not have the column of XXX.

The table doesn't contain the XXX column.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is incorrect, because "does not" is contracted to "doesn't."  "Don't" is the contraction of "do not."  Remember, it should be "it does" not "it do."  The way you say it right now, you say, "It does do not" which is incorrect.  I also think that it's more natural to say "an XXX column" instead of "a column of XXX" whenever it makes sense gramatically.

I think the clearest way of saying this would be:

"The table is missing an XXX column."

If you want to emphasize that the problem is true, you could say:

"The report is right.  The table is missing an XXX column."